# Purpose of TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage while setting WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have just begun to learn how to set low level keyboard hooks in Windows using C++.

Here is a small code I have written to get started.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

HHOOK hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *p = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
    std::cout << nCode << " - " << wParam << " - " << p->vkCode << std::endl;
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHook, NULL, NULL);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    MSG messages;
    std::cout << "Waiting for messages ..." << std::endl;
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        std::cout << "Got message" << std::endl;
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        std::cout << "Translated message" << std::endl;
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
        std::cout << "Dispatched message" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this in this manner:

```
vcvars32.bat
cl /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0401 foo.cc /link user32.lib
```

When I execute the code and press <kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>B</kbd> I get an output like the following:

```
C:\>foo
Waiting for messages ...
0 - 257 - 13
0 - 256 - 65
0 - 257 - 65
0 - 256 - 66
0 - 257 - 66
```

Why do I never see `Got message` in the output? Why does the control never enter the `while` loop? Can someone help me understand the purpose of `GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` here? I have read the documentation, but I guess I am missing something because I fail to understand how they are useful since I am never able to invoke the body of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetMessage()` function waits until a message arrives for one of the windows created by your process. Since you have created no windows, you will receive no messages.

Comment: This helps me to understand what `GetMessage` does. However, I do not understand why `GetMessage` is required in this code then. I see that if I omit the `while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))` loop and use `while(true)` loop, I am unable to capture any keystrokes at all. So it seems I need the `while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))` in order to capture keystrokes. Now if `GetMessage()` is not required since I am not creating any window, how can I rewrite the above code without `GetMessage` to capture and display keystrokes? Should I create a separate StackOverflow question for this?

Comment: Well, `GetMessage()` actually does many things behind the scenes to enable message delivery. However, it will only return *with a message for you* if you have created a window. So it still is required even though you will never receive any window messages.